# Varien Autoloader thinks my module's observer lives in Mage/

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, module, varien-autoload

I inherited a couple of Magento installs with custom observers to handle integration with SAP B1. The B1 parts I get, but Magento keeps throwing curveballs at me that I just can't get good answers about. I have searched on SE, and found a few people with the same error messages, but none of their fixes/causes seem to be affecting me.

Whenever cron.php runs, I get the following 3 errors every time:

```
2015-02-25T00:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/CompanyName/AutomatedImport/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /chroot/home/shop/shop.companyname.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-02-25T00:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/CompanyName/AutomatedImport/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /chroot/home/shop/shop.companyname.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-02-25T00:30:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/CompanyName/AutomatedImport/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/chroot/home/shop/shop.companyname.com/html/app/code/local:/chroot/home/shop/shop.companyname.com/html/app/code/community:/chroot/home/shop/shop.companyname.com/html/app/code/core:/chroot/home/shop/shop.companyname.com/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /chroot/home/shop/shop.companyname.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

The problem is, my modules are located exactly where they are supposed to be in *app/code/local/CompanyName/AutomatedImport*, and not under **Mage/**. I've got another Magento install for a different shop that uses almost the exact same modules (they maybe vary by 5 lines of non-important code) and that one works fine.

Has anyone run into this before? I have a feeling it's some stupid capitalization issue somewhere in my *module/etc/config.xml* or in *app/etc/modules/CompanyName_AutomatedImport.xml* but I can't for the life of me find anything that tells me that what I have is in any way wrong. I've been attempting to do due diligence on this for the past week and a half, but I just don't know enough about Magento. All of the SO fixes I've seen involve either problems in the xml that I don't have, or moving modules/Magento installs into different directories/servers, which I haven't done.

Any help would be most appreciated, as I am way past stumped.

[Module config.xml](http://pastebin.com/vZGFfbnT)

[app/etc/modules xml file](http://pastebin.com/jhecyb8T)

**Things attempted:**

- Turning on/off caching
- Clearing the cache(s)
- Turning on compilation mode, and turning it back off
- Checking the permissions on my module

Comment: Did you clear configuration cache?

Comment: I have. I've turned off/on caching, cleared the cache(s), and turned on/off compilation mode. That's a good point, I should mention those things in the post.

Comment: Next thing that comes to mind is a file permission problem. The error happens if Magento can't find the observer class, finally falls back to the Mage namespace, which results in these messages

Comment: The directories are 775 all the way up past my namespace, and both my user and the user that Magento uses are in the same group.

Comment: My worry is that my XML has some capitalization error, or a place where I was supposed to put the namespace but didn't, or visa versa.

Comment: Yep. Found it ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your `config.xml` you have the line:

```
<model>CompanyName_AutomatedImport/Observer::automatedImportProcess</model>
```

The first part of this expression should be either the class name

```
CompanyName_AutomatedImport_Model_Observer
```

or the alias that you defined in `<models>`

```
companyname_automatedumport/observer
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my situation is unchanged :( I changed it to <model>companyname_automatedimport/observer::automatedImportProcess</model>, and the result is the same

Comment: JTry with the class name instead. If it works then, it's a configuration problem, if not, a problem with the file/class

Answer (score 1):

Did you change server (PHP version, OS, etc.) when you inherited? This is mostly likely due to the non-leading upper-cased letter in `AutomatedImport`. There's some case sensitivity issues across platforms and/or PHP versions (not entirely sure exactly which causes it). It may need to be `Automatedimport`.

I always only capitalize the first letter of directories and files for this reason when developing Magento extensions. Basically, your `companyname_automatedimport` and `CompanyName_AutomatedImport` are not matching up for Magento.

Comment: The server/PHP version is the same as when it was first installed, thankfully. Those capitalization issues - is that just in the config files, or should I be concerned that my namespace directory is "Company**N**ame" as well?

Comment: Hm probably.. Different OS then? I know on my local OS X instances, capitalization is not an issue. It had often caused issues on production environments running Linux or something similar. I just avoid middle capitalization now. Can you try making a dummy extension with both cases of capitalization, and try instantiating your observer with `Mage::getModel()`? This will certainly tell you if it's a case issue.